# Is there any way to change this light bulb? (no socket I guess)

Tags: electrical, lighting

My ceiling lamp died. Is there any way that I can change this light bulb?
The white wires are soldered into the ballast inside the box. The ballast also is wired to pins connect to the bulb. So I guess I have to change the whole thing, both bulb and the ballast?

Also how to disconnect the connector on the left?

[image: The bulb]

Comment: Can you give us a closeup of the connector on the left?

Answer (score 6):

Usually, with those types of "2D" fluorescent tubes, you grasp the central plastic portion and pull down firmly. There are pins in the underside that are gripped by a receptacle in the fitting.

[A video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hh-IIQE3lcI)
[Another](https://youtu.be/M-vqX3bnRfo?t=92)

Here's some randomly selected  instructions

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks. Managed to get the lamp out. Did break one of the clips on the side though :(. Hopefully it will still hold a new bulb.

Comment: @trinho: Make sure you get the same type replacement, there are 2-pin and 4-pin variants and a couple of different sizes (large, small).

Answer (score 3):

I did a google search on circular fluorescent light and came up with this picture.
[image: Light]

It does not have any leads going to it, it looks like a socket connection. The wires just happen to go behind that area. Remove the retainer and unplug the bulb.

Answer (score 1):

The power plug at the lower left side of the photo is first unplugged (it should pull apart).

Next remove the screw and clip shown in the photo at the center of the fixture. Have a helper hold the bulb as it may become loose.

The bulb should now be free of the fixture and tha new bulb is installed in reverse order.